# Spark SQL- GC memory overhead exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to execute multiple queries through spark sql (sqlcontext). It taking more time and memory then goes to GC memory overhead error due to more shuffling and sorting based on union all.

```
val joinDF = sqlContext
   .sql(rule3qry.dropRight(7))
   .unionAll(sqlContext.sql(rule3qry.dropRight(7)))
   .unionAll(sqlContext.sql(rule4qry.dropRight(7)))
   .unionAll(sqlContext.sql(rule5qry.dropRight(7)))
```

then hit the cassandra DB at single time.

"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to acquire 20 bytes of memory, got 0
    at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.allocatePage(MemoryConsumer.java:120)"

Above is the error in the cluster log. 
Please suggest how to execute these multiple query without union all functions.

Comment: Can you not combine all the queries into one so that the load is not on spark if it is from the same database?

Comment: Hi, Everything is different table and their own logic. So I created different DF and combined by using unionall function. I Don't know how to combine it without unionall function